# Splash Screen shows gray colour background instead of image in Samsung s5

Tags: android

In my application,the splash screen image for Samsung S5 does not appear properly.Instead of working in Genymotion but not on real device of Samsung S5. Also working on other mobile phone.Below is my style.xml file and in Splash screen i have added one handler consisting using intent 
    Complete style file is not able to add,so i have provided some useful code
            Please help me.

styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"></style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarker</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="floatingHintEditTextStyle">@style/Widget.FloatingHintEditText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>
    <style name="PauseDialogAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/zoom_in</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/zoom_out</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.Transparent.splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

Comment: what theme are you using for you activity

Comment: android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent.splash"

Comment: try no action bar

Comment: what are your image dimensions?

Comment: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"

Comment: With theme nothing happens

Comment: 1039*1852 resolution

Comment: Its a high resolution image. Better to use low resolution image or load your image using _Universal Image Loader_

Comment: Post your `SplashActivity` and `styles.xml` code.

Comment: @Shivangi put some code too! So that it will help each of us to understand the real issue!

Comment: Please add some code. It is hard to understand your problem.

Comment: Actually in code,only handler is there which contains of Intent so i have not posted code

Comment: I had this kind of problems with high dimensional images. Lower your image dimensions and test it.

Comment: Not working with small dimensional image also

Comment: show me your xml file

Comment: It works with small dimensional image . Thanku all for your help